# Студия 2019 в режиме дебагинга окно проекта пропадает

Tags: visual-studio, компиляция, visual-studio-2019

Я поставил себе студию 2019 и сейчас компиляция проекта (именно в режиме дебагинга) происходит как то странно. Если проект ранее не был запущен в режиме дебагинга, то он сначала не на долго запускается, работает, после чего окно проекта пропадает (имею ввиду окно моего проекта - если консолька то консоль пропадает если гуи то мое гуи) и далее вновь запускается менее чем через секунду - при втором запуске уже можно производить отладку.

У всех ли так ? можно ли как то от подобного избавиться ?

Answer (score 0):

Да. В режиме отладки свой профиль отображения окон. Вам просто нужно открыть окно проекта, или другое нужное окно, после перехода в режим отладки.

Comment: Не понял Вас. Т.е. в 19 студии у Вас тоже в режиме отладки проект по 2 раза запускается верно? Как вы с этим справились ? В 17 студии подобного у меня небыло